# Jupyter Notebook file is taking forever to upload on Github

Tags: github, file-upload, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I was trying to upload one of my Jupyter Notebook files on **GitHub**, but it's taking forever to upload.

File size is also not that big. It's about 17KB. Also getting problem for this notebook only.

Here's the screen shot.

[image: Screen Shot]

Any kind of help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Git Bash to push your code/make changes instead of uploading files directly on GitHub (it is less prone to errors and is quite comfortable at times - takes less time as well!), for doing so, you may follow the below-given steps:

1. Download and install the latest version of Git Bash from here - https://git-scm.com/
2. Right-click on any desired location on your system.
3. Click “Git Bash Here”.
4. git config --global user.name “your name”
5. git config --global user.email “your email”
6. Go back to your GitHub account – open your project – click on “clone” – copy HTTPS
   link.
7. git clone PASTE HTTPS LINK.
8. Clone of your GitHub project will be created on your computer location.
9. Open the folder and paste your content.
10. Make sure content is not empty
11. Right-click inside the cloned folder where you have pasted your content.
12. Click “Git Bash Here” again.
13. You will find (master) appearing after your location address.
14. git add .
15. Try git status to check if all your changes are marked in green.
16. git commit --m “Some message”
17. git push origin master

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Tanvi Penumudy. I'll do same

Answer (score 1):

You could try and:

- clone the repository, add the file locally, commit and push
- check on github.com if your remote repository has a .gitattributes file with **`lfs`** directives in it.

Maybe that repository, [managed by LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), has reached some upload limit which would prevent any new upload.

Comment: Thank you, Actually I deleted the sub-folder where I was trying to upload it. So it worked.